# Building a Markdown, Math Notation, Syntax Highlighting Text Editor

Tags: text-editor, markdown, latex

I want to have a text editor like that of *SO* and and *math.stackexchange.com*. That will work on web browsers like that of *SE*.

- I need some level of markup support
- and also math notation support like *mathjax* gives
- syntax highlighting
- For ease of use I also want to have some buttons for easy access to the mostly used math symbols, and text formatting

A text editor like *math.stackexchange.com* will be my final target, both *markdown*, *syntax highlighting*, and *math notation*.

I have searched and found out that SO, and SE in general, uses *PageDown* for markup support, and *mathjax* (not SO) for math notation support. Mathjax itself is out there for free usage. There is *StackEdit* also, with building on top of these two and some others.

My question of what path should I follow to build what I need and want? Should I get building it from a single `<textarea>` and utilizing the open source tools like *PageDown*, *Mathjax* and some others maybe?

What tools should I use that will go well together as I need some distinct features that will be provided by separate tools?

Comment: Take a look at Jupyter - http://jupyter.org/ especially the notebooks functionality.

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but the description for [Markdown Notes](http://markdownnotes.com/) looks like it is very much along the lines you are looking for.